Can an animated GIF image have two frames with two different dimensions?
Can an animated GIF image have two frames with two different dimensions? Or must all frames in a GIF have the same dimension?

From a quick glance at the specification it would seem like the different frames can have different dimensions:
From 20. Image Descriptor.
  c. Syntax.

    7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0        Field Name                    Type
   +---------------+
0  |               |       Image Separator               Byte
   +---------------+
1  |               |       Image Left Position           Unsigned
   +-             -+
2  |               |
   +---------------+
3  |               |       Image Top Position            Unsigned
   +-             -+
4  |               |
   +---------------+
5  |               |       Image Width                   Unsigned
   +-             -+
6  |               |
   +---------------+
7  |               |       Image Height                  Unsigned
   +-             -+
8  |               |
   +---------------+
9  | | | |   |     |       <Packed Fields>               See below
   +---------------+

However the GIF image as a whole must have one dimension as seen in 18. Logical Screen Descriptor.
c. Syntax.

    7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0        Field Name                    Type
   +---------------+
0  |               |       Logical Screen Width          Unsigned
   +-             -+
1  |               |
   +---------------+
2  |               |       Logical Screen Height         Unsigned
   +-             -+
3  |               |
   +---------------+
4  | |     | |     |       <Packed Fields>               See below
   +---------------+
5  |               |       Background Color Index        Byte
   +---------------+
6  |               |       Pixel Aspect Ratio            Byte
   +---------------+

The dimensions for the actual frames cannot exceed the dimensions for the image as a whole:
From 20. Image Descriptor.

a. Description. Each image in the Data Stream is composed of an Image
Descriptor, an optional Local Color Table, and the image data.  Each
image must fit within the boundaries of the Logical Screen, as defined
in the Logical Screen Descriptor.

(Bolding mine, not present in the original text)
TL;dr: The image as a whole must have one dimension, but the different frames can have different dimensions so long as they are smaller.
